# recieved memory warning and crash the app when capture more than 4 images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, didreceivememorywarning

In my app I need to upload 6 images to a server. I capture the image then upload it and then go to the next one and do the same.

When I reach the 5th image and after receiving 3 or 4 memory warning the app crashes

Here is the code of the image picker

```
-(void) TakePhotoWithCamera {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker1.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker1.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Here is the method when finishing the capture

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIButton * tappedBtn = (UIButton *) [self.horizontalScrollView viewWithTag:chosenImgBtnTag];
    [tappedBtn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self useImage:img];   // this method upload the image to the server
    info = nil;
}
```

here is the method of the setImage

```
 - (void) useImage:(UIImage *) image {

    currentImageToUpload = image;
   [self showLoadingIndicatorOnImages];
   [[CarAdsManager sharedInstance] uploadImage:image WithDelegate:self];
 }
```

so please any help in this matter ?

Comment: Do you release picker1 before allocating a new one?

Comment: am using ARC so am not using release method

Comment: Do you ARC? What happens in `useImage:` ?

Comment: i just put the method ,, it calls the api so i can upload to the server

Comment: Have you checked the below answer?. It solved the same problem.

Comment: try it but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should re-size`(480, 480)` your image after captured the image like followed,

```
UIImage *getNewImage;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(480, 480);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[capturedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
getNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It will return "getNewImage" as a image. You can upload this image. It will reduce your memory warning crash.

Comment: just try it ,, but nothing new ,still the same problem it uploading faster but keep crashing after capture 4th image

Comment: dismiss your viewcontroller and then use your image to the next view controller. It may helps you.

Comment: i found the solution , it was to define the picker as static